# How do I handle specific SQL exceptions (for example, a unique constraint violation) in C#?

Tags: c#, exception

my question is how to handle sql exception in c#, is there anyway to check what kind of the sql exception throws from data access layer? For example, if db throws an unique constraint exception, or foreign key exception, is there any way to catch it from c#? what's the exception handling pattern you are using for these db exception?

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at the [documentation of the SqlException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx) class, in particular, at its [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception_properties.aspx): [`SqlException.Number`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx), for example, should allow you to identify which type of SqlException (unique constraint, foreign key, ...) occurred.

You can use filtered exceptions to catch specific errors. VB.NET:

```
Try
    ...
Catch ex as SqlException When ex.Number = ...
    ...
Catch ex as SqlException When ex.Number = ...
    ...
End Try
```

C# (Version 6 and above):

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (SqlException ex) when (ex.Number == ...)
{
    ...
}
catch (SqlException ex) when (ex.Number == ...)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: According to the documentation, this exception class is specific to SQL Server, so not applicable to Oracle, MySql, etc.

Comment: @Gooseberry: True, but the same principle applies to other data providers: `OleDbException` has an `Errors` property, `SqliteException` has an `SqliteErrorCode` property, etc. The OP did not specify which data provider they use.

Answer (score 2):

you can check message text,Number and do switch case on it to know the error...

```
try {
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
 string str;
        str = "Source:"+ ex.Source;        
        str += "\n"+ "Number:"+ ex.Number.ToString();
        str += "\n"+ "Message:"+ ex.Message;
        str += "\n"+ "Class:"+ ex.Class.ToString ();
        str += "\n"+ "Procedure:"+ ex.Procedure.ToString();
        str += "\n"+ "Line Number:"+ex.LineNumber.ToString();
        str += "\n"+ "Server:"+ ex.Server.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine (str, "Database Exception");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the exception and your database backend.  You database will produce a unique error code for the specific things like constraints, permissions, etc.  but that error code varies from DB to DB.  Oracle has a MASSIVE pdf (2000+ pages) that lists every possible error it can throw and I am sure Sqlserver has something similar.  My point is you looking for specific error codes then you need to trp just those in the catch section and handle them differently then the multitude of other errors you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Catch SqlException

```
catch(SqlException ex)
{
    foreach(SqlError error in ex.Errors)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general-purpose exception class is [DbException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbexception), but you'd be limited to parsing the error message text.

For finer-grained handling, you'll need to catch the provider-specific implementation of DbException for the specific DB you are using.  These usually provide access to the error code and other details.  Here are some common ones:

- For SQL Server DB, [SqlException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception)
- For Oracle DB, [OracleException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracleexception)
- For MySql DB, [MySqlException](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlException.htm)
- For SQLite DB, [SQLiteException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqliteexception)