# How to Handle error code in c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have a problem in C# in how to handle Error in `try` - `catch`.

Example I write code for delete record into database but this record has FK into another table. How to handle this?

```
try
{
     // delete record in database
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    int error = // how to get this code exception      
}
```

Comment: You can refer the following link.. hope it may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403348/how-can-i-know-if-an-sqlexception-was-thrown-because-of-foreign-key-violation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try
{
    # SQL Stuff
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Errors.Count > 0) // Assume the interesting stuff is in the first error
    {
        switch (ex.Errors[0].Number)
        {
            case 547: // Foreign Key violation
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Some helpful description", ex);
                break;
            case 2601: // Primary key violation
                throw new DuplicateRecordException("Some other helpful description", ex);
                break;
            default:
                throw new DataAccessException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

as per [foreign-key-violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403348/how-can-i-know-if-an-sqlexception-was-thrown-because-of-foreign-key-violation)

Take a look at:
    [how-to-handle-db-exception-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666887/how-to-handle-db-exception-in-c-sharp)

Which will tell you how to precisely locate the foreign key error.

Also look at [MSDN Row Deletion including foreign keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386925.aspx)

Which explains about setting cascade to on - which is what I believe you are missing.

Answer (score 2):

You may catch [SQLException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx) instead of general `Exception` and use its [Number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx) property

```
 catch (SqlException ex)
    {
     Console.WriteLine(ex.Number);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Exception` will hold details of the error type
If you want to catch a specific type of Exception, use that type in the catch.
eg:

```
 catch (SqlException sqlex)
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adam_nathan/archive/2003/04/25/56643.aspx) for Win32.For Database use SqlException Class.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{  
  //exec delete command
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
  //if SQL error indicates referential integrity violation
    throw ReferentialIntegrityViolationException// or whatever
}
```

Comment: @ O.D: How to get this error into which group, example delete in data base into SQLException , but another into which group? thanks

Comment: @M.B: what do mean into which group?

Comment: Example when user want delete record and this record fk to another table fierd error into SQLException

Comment: Ok so you catch it as shown in the answer and provide an errormessage which you show to the user.

Comment: instead of throw ReferentialIntegrityViolationException you can provide the user with the Message that a failure is occured

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    // your code to run
}
catch(SqlException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
} 
// Catch all Exceptions
catch(Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Message);
}
```